# tee not working in script but working in bash

Tags: bash, grep, tee

So i'm trying to take the line-by-line output of a program, then send it to a file if it matches "CPU", also I want every line to go to the screen.

This command works but only after quitting the script with ^C:

```
cpuminer-multi/cpuminer -u user -p pass -a sha256d -o stratum+tcp://stratum.pool.com:3333 -t cputhreads | tee >(grep "CPU" >> cpu.txt);
```

but then if I copy and paste it into a bash script "start.sh"

```
#!/bin/bash

cpuminer-multi/cpuminer -u user -p pass -a sha256d -o stratum+tcp://stratum.pool.com:3333 -t cputhreads | tee >(grep "CPU" >> cpu.txt);
```

and run it from bash as "./start.sh", it populates cpu.txt with nothing, even after quitting with ^C

So my questions are

A: Why does it only populate the cpu.txt file after ^C?

B: Why does it work as a plain bash command, but not in a script?

Comment: Try using `grep --line-buffered` and see if that helps.

Comment: Yesss, that seems to have fixed that problem. Super Thanks.

Only if I replace "grep "CPU" >> cpu.txt" with "grep "CPU" > cpu.txt" it still appends and doesnt overwrite.

Comment: You can try with sed : cpuminer... | sed '/CPU/w cpu.txt'

Comment: You could replace `tee >(grep "CPU" >> cpu.txt);` with `awk '/CPU/{print > "cpu.txt"}1'`.

Comment: wow these are all great answers, thanks guys, but how do I actually set one of them to be the answer on stackoverflow?
So I click "Answer Your Question" then just copy paste your answers in?